Programatically Select eventMarker with Anychart Stock v8
How do I programmatically choose which eventMarker is selected using Anychart Stock? I have a modal that appears when you click a eventMarker to provide more info, and I want to be able to navigate between the markers using he modal rather than having to click on the graph again
(this seems to have been possible in previous versions, but I can't seem to figure it out in v8)
see example of previous version: https://6.anychart.com/products/stock/online-demos/html-js-samples-center/selecting-event-markers/index.html#sampleView
When reviewing the documentation (https://docs.anychart.com/Stock_Charts/Event_Markers/Basics#individual_markers) I cannot find any methods that can select a specific eventMarker, only configure the behavior when eventMarkers are selected
